# How do I change the path to a Data Feed in a PowerPivot workbook?

Tags: .net, excel, ssas, powerpivot

Here's the scenario.  I'm building PowerPivot reports that I need to publish on a SharePoint 2010 site.  The reports need to refresh the underlying data nightly - all of the data comes from SharePoint lists.

I have created the datafeed files that I need and published them to a trusted document library.  I have created the workbooks that I need and published them to a trusted document library.  When I'm ready to deploy my updated solution from my dev to qa to uat to production environments, I have to change the path of the data-feeds to reflect the new server name.

Anybody know how to do that programatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2013, this blog post will help

http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/import-data-into-the-model-using-a-macro-in-excel-2013

It shows how to add/edit conenction using macros. This should be portable to other technologies like .Net. The key line in the sample macro is

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2 Name:="AzureDataMarketPlaceDataFeed", _
                                       Description:="My Data Feed", _
                                       ConnectionString:=MyConnStr, _
                                       CommandText:="demog1", _
                                       CreateModelConnection:=True
```

The last part of this causes the model connection to be set.

As far as I know, this is **not possible** in earlier versions of Excel/PowerPivot. The change has been enabled by the deeper and more native integration of the PowerPivot in-memory database engine into Excel 2013 compared to 2010.